# Unable to start Virtual Box in redhat 6.5

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, redhat, virtualization

I have installed virtual box - VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.22_115126_el6-1.x86_64.rpm in redhat 6.5 but while starting virtual box, I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.
"

**From /var/log/messages:**

> May 22 20:12:07 MSS-SWM abrtd: send-mail: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory May 22 20:12:07 MSS-SWM abrtd: Error running
>   '/bin/mailx' May 22 20:12:07 MSS-SWM abrtd: 'post-create' on
>   '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2017-05-22-20:11:55-141657' exited with 1 May 22
>   20:12:07 MSS-SWM abrtd: Deleting problem directory
>   '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2017-05-22-20:11:55-141657' May 22 20:21:24
>   **MSS-SWM kernel: VirtualBox[143266]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fddf7914781
>   sp 00007fffa28a7b70 error 4 in
>   libQt5CoreVBox.so.5[7fddf7850000+598000]**

could you please help on this.

Comment: Are all your dependencies there?  Have a look at this link https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-on-redhat-centos-fedora/

Comment: RHEL 6.5 is an old version. Current is RHEL **6.9** . Which is what you get when doing # `yum update`

Answer (score 0):

The following is presented in the link I provided in my comments:

add virtual box repo

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
# wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/rhel/virtualbox.repo
```

install dependencies

```
# yum update
# yum install binutils qt gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel dkms
```

If you don't have access to the internet, but do have the CentOS DVD, try

mounting the DVD to your system (to `/media/cdrom/` for example)

running `yum` to install the rpm packages from the DVD as such:

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=c5-media install binutils qt gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel dkms
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. Since machine is not connected to internet, I cant perform the above task which you have mentioned. As mentioned in my post, I have a virtual box rpm and am able to install the rpm without any trouble, but upon issuing $virtualbox command, I am getting that error message. How do I resolve this issue in offline?